# How can I make vulkan-hpp not throw certain kinds of exceptions?

Tags: vulkan

I'm writing
`presentQueueue.presentKHR(presentInfo)`
and I want an exception not to be thrown when `result = vk::Result::eErrorOutOfDateKHR`
(because in this case I will recreate the swapchain). VULKAN_HPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS no need. How can I make vulkan-hpp ignore some results?

Comment: It'd be easy enough to write your own version of the function which swallows that specific exception.